# Sending PHP array to JS function called in echoed string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and want to send it as a parameter to JS function. Google told me that `json_encode()` is the way to go, but I get an *unterminated string literal* error when I try to call the function.

Here's my code:

```
$wynik_artefakty = $polaczenie->query("SELECT * FROM artefakty"); 
$tablica_artefakty = mysqli_fetch_all($wynik_artefakty,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$tablica_artefakty = json_encode($tablica_artefakty);

 echo "<div class='wpis' 
       onclick=\"dodajDiv('$tablica_artefakty')\">" 
      .$tablica_jednostek[$i]['nazwa']." ".$tablica_jednostek[$i]['koszt']."</div>";
```

And the example echo of the array after `json_encode()`:

```
[{"Id":"2","nazwa":"Sceptre of Atrocities","personal":"The 
Gorgon","dla_maga":"0","koszt":"15"},{"Id":"3","nazwa":"Artefakt dla 
maga","personal":"","dla_maga":"1","koszt":"10"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the string you're injecting from `$tablica_artefakty` contains quotes. This causes your HTML be improperly rendered - attribute is prematurely closed by the quote from your string. You should escape the quotes in your `$tablica_artefakty` so that they don't close the HTLM attributes in wrong places.